# JavaScript url to input text?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input field where users can be searched.

I want to have it so if someone puts their username in the url, the input field has that text that was inputted in the url

Ex:

https://website.com/username = 'username' in input field value

Comment: So what problem are you having accomplishing this? Show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is `window.location.href` it'll let you get the current URL, from that you can parse the username.

```js
let parse = window.location.href;
console.log(parse)
parse = parse.split('/');
console.log(parse[parse.length -1])
```